# Google Cloud AppEngine and Django: how should I set the domain name for have it work?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've deployed a Django project on Google Cloud standard AppEngine,

- My Domain Name is registered in Google Domains which confirms that it already points to my project when I try to customize my domains.
- On the Web, I've access my project under its project name:
  `https://mooveup-9645.oa.r.appspot.com`
- However when I try `https://my-domain.fr` the web site cannot be accessed.
  My Question is:
  Where should I add my domain name ?

```
if APPENGINE_URL:
    # Ensure a scheme is present in the URL before it's processed.
    if not urlparse(APPENGINE_URL).scheme:
        APPENGINE_URL = f"https://{APPENGINE_URL}"

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(APPENGINE_URL).netloc, "www.my-domain.fr", "my-domain.fr"]
```

Is this the appropriate solution in Django settings or is there another configuration step with GCP?

Comment: Showing your DNS records might help in case you have a mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the Custom Domain in the GCP console:

[https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains?project={your_project}](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains?project=%7Byour_project%7D)

Answer (score 0):

On Google Cloud tutorial to deploy an Django project on AppEngine, some steps are skipped.

1. On Django Settings complete the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` with your domain name.
2. If you have a Standard AppEngine in order to avoid the overload of the Engine, the better is to deploy and then delete the former versions, in order to alleviate the risk of  Error `502`:

```
$ gcloud app deploy --project PROJECT_ID --promote
$ gcloud app versions list --project PROJECT_ID  //to get the older versions
$ gcloud app versions delete VERSION_ID
```

Then: 
On `https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings`, you should customize your domain name and end your domain name with a DOT in order to get the DNS records and then update them on `https://domains.google.com/registrar/`